# What dice are used for the Adult Oblex's Eat Memories?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, dice

The relevant portion of [the creatures stat block](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/mordenkainens-tome-of-foes#AdultOblex):

> **Eat Memories.** [...]
> While memory drained, the target must roll a d4 and subtract the number rolled from any ability check or attack roll it makes. Each time the target is memory drained beyond the first, the die size increases by one: the d4 becomes a d6, the d6 becomes a d8, and so on until the die becomes a d20, at which point the target becomes unconscious for 1 hour. The effect then ends.

The standard dice used in DND have 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, and 20 sides.

**Does the ability therefore skip from 12 to 20? Or does it continue to increase by 2 each time - hitting 14, 16, and 18 - as implied by the examples in the stat block?**

There is precedent for use of non-standard dice, such as a d3 used in the [Wild Magic Barbarian's Bolstering Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/tashas-cauldron-of-everything#PathofWildMagic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The rules never mention any d14

The stat block indicates that we use d4, d6, d8  ... d20. Since the text is not 100 % clear on what comes between 8 and 20, we have to consider precedence.

While the rules of DnD 5e never to my knowledge mention a d14, there is a list of the dice used in the game (PHB p. 6). This list mentions the standard dice, *i.e.* d12 and d20 and nothing in-between.

You take a d3 as example of a die that also appears even if it is not of the 6 standard dice.  The same paragraph (PHB p. 6-7) also explains non-standard dice and how to emulate them using standard dice. Those are d2, d3 and d100, but not d14.

**Tl;dr: Since the stat block does not clarify the exact dice used, we have to assume the standard types of dice are used, which means a d20 after a d12.**

Comment: I would also point out, while the jump from 12 to 20 is very large, it also happens as a result of being repeatedly affected by the drain. As far as I can tell, RAI is that this is bad and should be remedied before it gets this dire.

Comment: Ah I did not know about the emulated d3! that's good info thank you.